# Making a Servlet reload the page it was called from

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have written a Servlet which completes a task and I want it to then reload the JSP that originally called the Servlet. The servlet runs of an `enctype='multipart/form-data'` JSP, this JSP is called Uploadtest, everytime I try to run either of the following code I get `The requested resource (/project_name/WebContent/jsps/new.jsp) is not available`.

I have tried:

```
response.sendRedirect("/WebContent/jsp/Uploadtest.jsp");
```

and

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WebContent/jsps/Uploadtest.jsp").forward   (request, response);
```

However both of these have produced an error saying it can't find the page I am looking for.

I am looking for any ideas on how I might fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Isn't WebContent a folder in your IDE ? That should not be in your URLs.

Answer (score 3):

You really need to understand the difference between the layout of the sources in your project, the layout of the deployed webapp, and the layout of the application in the server.

The deployed webapp has the following structure:

```
jsps
    Uploadtest.jsp
WEB-INF
    classes
        the compiled classes of your application
    lib
        the jars of your application
```

The WebContent directory doesn't exist in the deployed app. It's just where Eclipse stores the webapp related sources (JSP files, images, etc.).

Each webapp has a context path. If the context path of your webapp is `/foo`, the path that you'll have to type in the browser's address bar for your JSP will be:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/jsps/Uploadtest.jsp
```

When you forward to another resource, it's always to a resource of the same webapp. So you don't need to specify the context path:

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/jsps/Uploadtest.jsp").forward (request, response);
```

When you redirect (which is completely different from a forward), you can redirect to any URL (the same webapp, another webapp on the same host, or www.google.com if you like). If you redirect to some resource of the same webapp, you don't need to send the `http://localhost:8080` part, but you need to send the context path, follwed by the resource path in the webapp, and you also should always use the encodeRedirectURL method (unless you don't care about users relying on URL-rewriting rather than cookies for session management):

```
String redirect = 
    response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + "/jsps/Uploadtest.jsp");
response.sendRedirect(redirect);
```

`request.getContextPath()` is used to get `/foo` without hard-coding it.

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is about the **structure of app** and the **specification of request url path**.

The first thing i want to point out, is the 'WebContent' is the virtual folder in eclipse. So you shouldnt use that in your request or redirect path.

The second, i guess you used absolute path to your app but with wrong coding:

1. there's a little mistake about typing:

> http:// localhost:8080/foo/jsp/Uploadtest.jsp

according your description, your should input:

```
http://localhost:8080/foo/jsps/Uploadtest.jsp
```

2.

```
getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WebContent/jsps/Uploadtest.jsp").forward   (request, response);
```

you should add the context path to your forward url like this:

```
request.getContextPath() + "jsps/Uploadtest.jsp"
```